# Testing Stripe with React Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments, react-testing-library

I've the following React components:

```js
const PaymentModal = () => {
    
    const stripePromise = loadStripe(apiKey);
    
    return(
        <div className = 'Modal'>
            <Elements stripe = {stripePromise}>
                <CheckoutForm/>
            </Elements>
        </div>
    );
    
}

const CheckoutForm = () => {

    return(
        <CardElement options = {{hidePostalCode: true}}/>
    );

}
```

And the following test:

```js
import React                                  from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent, screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import PaymentModal                           from '../Components/PaymentModal';

test('PaymentModal -> Payment works in test mode', async () => {
    
    render(
          <PaymentModal/>
    );
    
    await screen.getByPlaceholderText('Número de tarjeta');
    
});
```

If I render the component without testing it, it renders the following:

```html
<input placeholder = "Número de tarjeta">
```

The problem is that the test fails and I'm getting the following error:

`TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the placeholder text of: Número de tarjeta`

Please, bear in mind that I don't want to mock-up the Stripe payment form. I want to test it by simulating a user introducing a dummy credit card number.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `await findByPlaceholderText(...)`, rather than `getBy...`? See https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async.

Comment: I get the same error.

Comment: @ErikMartínJordán were you able to solve this? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @SahilDeliwala no, still not solved...

Comment: hmm.. without mocking it is causing issue. It works with mocking like this: https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-js/blob/4237a54805dc303cdd734d5f8b36a9b20959e83d/src/components/Elements.test.tsx#L33

Comment: has this been fixed yet?

Comment: This is not possible. Explained and answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75616588/react-testing-library-is-not-calling-the-onready-listener-of-stripes-paymentele/77360959#77360959:~:text=You%20can%27t%20because,in%20the%20document

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent, screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import PaymentModal from '../Components/PaymentModal';

test('PaymentModal -> Payment works in test mode', async () => {
  render(<PaymentModal />);

  await waitFor(() =>
    expect(screen.getByPlaceholderText('Número de tarjeta')).toBeInTheDocument()
  );
});
```

Comment: This is not possible. Explained and answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75616588/react-testing-library-is-not-calling-the-onready-listener-of-stripes-paymentele/77360959#77360959:~:text=You%20can%27t%20because,in%20the%20document