# React testing library is not calling the onReady listener of Stripe's PaymentElement component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, stripe-payments, react-testing-library

I'm using the `Elements` and `PaymentElement` components from `@stripe/react-stripe-js` and disabled the loader to implement a custom solution. This works fine in the UI:

```
const [isStripeLoading, setIsStripeLoading] = useState(true);

const onFormReady = () => {
  setIsStripeLoading(false);
};

return (
  <Elements stripe={stripe} options={ { loader: 'never' } }>
    {isStripeLoading && (
      <div className="payment-methods__stripe-element-experiment--icon">
        <Icon type="Loading" />
      </div>
    )}
    <PaymentElement
      onReady={onFormReady}
    />
  </Elements>
)
```

How would I write a test with React Testing Library to reflect this state change `onReady`?

I tried to render the Wrapper component which is itself wrapped in a `react-redux` Provider, but it never sets `isStripeLoading` to `false`.

```
const renderComponent = async (state: typeof initialState) => {
  const store = configureStore(state, reducers);
  return await render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <CheckoutForm {...props} />
    </Provider>
  );
};

describe('CheckoutForm', () => {

  it('should render', async () => {
    let container;
    await act(async () => {
      container = await renderComponent(initialState);
    });

    const { getByTestId } = container;
    expect(getByTestId('stripe-payment-element')).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you want to replace/mock the Stripe element and fire the event manually to test the handler & loader behaviour:

https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/faq -> "How do I test input onChange handlers?"
https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-events

You might need to reach out to the testing library community/authors to get help if that doesn't allow you to test this ready event.

Answer (score 0):

You can't because its not in the DOM so there is no way to detect that `<PaymentElement | CardElement/>` is ready or has loaded.

["When testing your Stripe app’s UI, you’re testing a remote engine that renders your app, not the Document Object Model (DOM) tree directly."](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-apps/ui-testing#:%7E:text=When%20testing%20your%20Stripe%20app%E2%80%99s%20UI%2C%20you%E2%80%99re%20testing%20a%20remote%20engine%20that%20renders%20your%20app%2C%20not%20the%20Document%20Object%20Model%20(DOM)%20tree%20directly.)

You can try this base in the [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-apps/ui-testing#rendering-a-component)

```
import {render} from '@stripe/ui-extension-sdk/testing';
import App from './App';

it('contains a Button', async () => {
  const {wrapper, update} = render(<App />);

  await update();

  // Continue testing...
});
```